# Rails belogs_to includes select query - ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two tables:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :order_lines
end
```

```
class OrderLine < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :order
end
```

I have a workflow in the code that generates below query:

```
OrderLine.includes(:order).select(:id).first
```

However, the above query results in `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: order_id`. I don't understand why am i getting this error. And how to fix it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have `order_id` coumlm inside `order_lines` table?

Comment: Yes i to have order_id column in order_lines table

Comment: Modify the query to something like this 
OrderLine.includes(:order).select(:id, :order_id).first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb#L230);

```
class ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader::Association::LoaderRecords
  ...

  def owner_key_name
    reflection.join_foreign_key
  end
end
```

which extracts the foreign key of the table that's in the `includes` call. As the ActiveRecord needs to know how to join which tables and load which records, then `order_lines.order_id` becomes a mandatory column in your select clause.

To fix it just add the `order_id` column to your select;

```
OrderLine.includes(:order).select(:id, :order_id).first
```